# Import and extract certain column and row

Tags: list-manipulation, import, csv-format

I have a problem with importing and extracting 2nd column in my CSV file. I need to have 3 list, the first one first column except for first row, the second will be second column except for 1st row and the last one will be 3rd column without first row.
I have succesfully imported and extracted the first column using:

```
Centre = Import["C:\\Users\\vocko01\\Desktop\\TS.csv", "Table", 
   "FieldSeparators" -> ";"][[2 ;;, 1]]
```

The third one works too:

```
Suburb = Import["C:\\Users\\vocko01\\Desktop\\TS.csv", "Table", 
   "FieldSeparators" -> ";"][[2 ;;, -1]]
```

But when I want to import and extract 2nd column, it doesn´t work the same way:

```
City = Import["C:\\Users\\vocko01\\Desktop\\TS.csv", "Table", 
   "FieldSeparators" -> ";"][[2 ;;, 2]]
```

Can you please help me with this issue or is it a better way to write it?

Thank you

Here is the link for CSV file: https://gofile.io/d/ELwAhG

Comment: As a general practice, I don't think it's a good idea to name a file .csv when it doesn't have comma separators.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: in principle I agree with your comment, but I know that it is common standard on at least German computers that .csv files use ";" as a separator because the German standard for NumberPoint is ",". For example if you save as csv from Excel on a German computer, it will use ";" as separator and most other spreadsheet apps do that as well.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Because of course... Yeah, I should've know that one. Dutch also uses commas as decimal separators, I just never used CSV on a Dutch computer (since I always set everything to English.). I just thought that something a ubiquitous as CSV would have a common international standard. Of course that would be too much to ask for...

Comment: @SjoerdSmit I had the exact same reaction to these comments, except I only speak English so I would have never even thought of it :) I should add support for ; in the native CSV importer because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data contains missing entries like: {{";0;0"}, {";0;87"}, {";0;"}}.
You must first repair the missing elements. Towards this aim, you first read the data as a string. Then you use `StringReplace` to add the missing pieces. Finally you import the data using `StringImport`

```
dat = Import["yourFileName", "String"];
dat = StringReplace[dat, {"\n;" -> "\n0;", ";\r" -> ";0\r"}];;
dat = ImportString[dat, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"];
```

Now you can extract the columns as before.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend importing the file like this to make it rectangular:

```
table = PadRight[
   Import["TS.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"],
   Automatic,
   Missing[]
];
Dimensions[table]
```

> {17349, 3}

Create a nice dataset:

```
dataset = Dataset[AssociationThread[First[table], #]& /@ Rest[table]]
```